# Awstats messaging non existant user causing exim4 to go nuts

Tags: exim, awstats

I've taken over managing a server set up by someone else now uncontactable, while managing to work out most faults / changes needed this one is stumping me. Awstats is running on the machine and sending messages via exim4 to a user every time it runs an update. The user account has been deleted and so the exim4 main log files are filling up with message delivery errors, which firstly hinders meaningful log analysis for anything else and secondly uses up quite a lot of space (it grew to 22GB unattended, panic!)

I've been through all the conf files in /etc/awstats and can't seem to find any mention of this user account. Google just turns up results about how to use awstats to parse exim4 log files.

So the questions is where is this setting (on debian) likely to be?

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue - put here in case anyone else ever has the same problem:

/etc/aliases had all the users going to root and then root going to the user account so all the system messages were being dumped into an unknown account.

Answer (score 1):

The updateprocess is probably started from crontab, which has the MAILTO= set.

Look in /var/spool/cron/crontabs. This is where the crontabs of all users are kept.

Otherwise, have a look in these files/directories: /etc/cron*.